# Is there any way to get Android Dialog box like the one in Google Apps?

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

Here is a screenshot of what I need :

[image: Link]
<sub>(source: [quoracdn.net](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-cbd68b56ed84c86bfad4f795c9cf809c-c))</sub>

I would like to add to my app a Dialbox like this, not the default ugly android one.

( [image: link] )

Is there any Google library (like Material ?) that allow me to do this without re-coding the whole thing in a fragment ?

Thanks

Comment: create custom dialog

Comment: There are many libraries that makes the same dialog as you wanted. These dialogues are called material dialog and I am sure that there is a support library for that. And if you don't want to go through the code then simply make a style in your style.xml file and pass the style to your dialog.

Comment: @Umair I'll have a look at the libs, thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

**Use bottom-sheet dialog.**

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout backgroundLayout;
    View bottomSheetView;
    TextView textPrompt1, textPrompt2;
    TextView textSDK;
    BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog;
    BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textPrompt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.prompt1);
        textPrompt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.prompt2);
        backgroundLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.backgroundlayout);

        bottomSheetView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottomsheetdialog_layout, null);
        bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);
        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) bottomSheetView.getParent());
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(bottomSheetCallback);

        bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                textPrompt1.setText("OnShow");
            }
        });

        bottomSheetDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                textPrompt1.setText("OnDismiss");
            }
        });

        backgroundLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                bottomSheetDialog.show();
            }
        });

    }

    BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback bottomSheetCallback =
            new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                    switch (newState){
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                            textPrompt2.setText("COLLAPSED");
                            break;
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                            textPrompt2.setText("DRAGGING");
                            break;
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                            textPrompt2.setText("EXPANDED");
                            break;
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                            textPrompt2.setText("HIDDEN");
                            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                            break;
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                            textPrompt2.setText("SETTLING");
                            break;
                        default:
                            textPrompt2.setText("unknown...");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

                }
            };
}
```

Create a file layout/bottomsheetdialog_layout.xml, to define the layout of the BottomSheetDialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Bottom Sheet Dialog Example"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Nice ! But I had to style it myself, I think i'll first go on GitHub libraries to see if I find something looking-like. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sure, you can try the other libraries as well. If u can to style as per requirement u can make changes to bottomsheetdialog_layout.xml file and call the dialog from common utility class.

Answer (score 0):

You can you [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) Fragment.

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

    //region Variables

    //options will be true if there is 2 option and false if there is a single option
    private boolean options;
    private WeakReference<DialogListener> mDialogListener;

    //endregion

    //region Constructors

    public CustomDialog() {
    }

    //endregion

    //region Instances

    public static CustomDialog newInstance(WeakReference<DialogListener> listener) {
        CustomDialog fragment = new CustomDialog();
        fragment.mDialogListener = listener;
        return fragment;
    }

    //endregion

    //region Lifecycle methods

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_layout,null);
        builder.setView(view);

        TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.alert_dialog);
        TextView positive = view.findViewById(R.id.positive);
        TextView negative = view.findViewById(R.id.negative);

        positive.setText("Ok");
        negative.setText("Cancel"));
        title.setText("title");


        positive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mDialogListener!=null) {
                    mDialogListener.get().onDialogPositiveClick(CustomDialog.this);
                }
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        negative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mDialogListener!=null) {
                    mDialogListener.get().onDialogNegativeClick(CustomDialog.this);
                }
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }

    //endregion

    //region Interface

    /**
     * Interface to tranasfer the click to the Dialogs host
     * The activity that creates an instance of this dialog fragment must
     * implement this interface in order to receive event callbacks.
     */
    public interface DialogListener {
        void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
        void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

    //endregion
}
```

and where ever you want to show it

```
DialogFragment c = CustomDialog.newInstance(new WeakReference<CustomDialog.DialogListener>(this));
c.setArguments(bundle);
c.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "dialogFrag");
```